# Parsing X-amf mime type data

Tags: flash, parsing, mime, amf, amfphp

I have intercepted x-amf data being posted to a website from my computer by a flash application. I have the collected POST data in hex form. While some of it has translated directly to text, the rest is showing wierd symbols which probably means they're flash objects. How do I parse this data to get meaningful output outta it?

Basically, I need a script/program/anything that will take in amf data in the hex form, and output text and flash objects...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your options are:

1. Firefox+Firebug+Flashbug
2. Charles proxy
3. python + pyamf
4. Java AMF client that comes with BlazeDS
5. Google )

Comment: Thanks. Charles proxy worked perfectly. Only wish it was freeware. However, seems like someone already beat me to it, and developed an app that can create the right requests to send to the flash app's server. Seems like they used Charles too.